# Node variable getting reset

Tags: node.js

I am working with 3 files in Nodejs. `File1.js1 has a`counter=11 and `getter() setter()`. `File2.js` sets the value to `counter=10`. But the when I retrieve the value of counter in `File3.js` I can the old value 1, instead of what was set by `File2`.

```
//=====File1.js=====

var store = module.exports = {
    counter: 1,
    getCounter: function () {
        return store.counter;
    },    
    setCounter: function (value) {
        store.counter = value;
    }
}

//=====File2.js=====

var c = require('./File1');    
c.setCounter(10);    
console.log(c.getCounter()) //prints 10

//=====File3.js=====

var c = require('./File1');    
console.log(c.getCounter()) //prints 1
```

This seems a simple and unfaltered concept. I think the problem is here, and I don't know how to resolve it.

File1 and File2 are running on Node-service-1 (available at http://localhost:1000) and File3 is running on Node-service-2 (available at http://localhost:1100).

In a typical scenario multiple users access Node-service-1 and Node-service-2 and only the first user gets 1000 available. I used `portfinder` package to get next available port and ran Node-service-1 for User2 on 1001. But Node-service-2 doesn't know that User2 is running the service on port 1001, and incorrectly tries to fetch 1000 (for User2) and fails.

So the question is how does Node-service-2 know the port on which Node-service-1 is running?

Answer (score 0):

If *file3.js* is running on a different node instance to *file2.js* then it will see a different instance of the *file1.js* module that the one *file2.js* sees. So consequently, you cannot use this method to communicate between the two scripts if they are running on separate node instances. If you need to communicate between two scripts on two node instances then you will either have to use a socket, shared memory or shared file (e.g. common database) based method to communicate.

Comment: I believe for socket connection too, i need to know the port on which Node-service-1 is running. Is that correct ?

Comment: Well, you would need to implement a socket listener on one node instance and then have code on the other instance connect to the correct port number. It would probably make more sense to research the different options available for communicating between node instances and choose an existing solution that best meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Julian Goacher I shall look into it further.